# Parsing XML with namespace into dictionary

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm having a hard time following the [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) documentation with regard to parsing an XML document with a namespace and nested tags.

To begin, the xml tree I am trying to parse looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT-MAIN xmlns="http://fakeurl.com/page">
    <Alarm> <--- I dont care about these types of objects
        <Node>
            <location>Texas></location>
            <name>John</name>
        </Node>
    </Alarm>
    <Alarm> <--- I care about these types of objects
        <CreateTime>01/01/2011</CreateTime>
        <Story>
            <Node>
                <Name>Ethan</name
                <Address category="residential>
                    <address>1421 Morning SE</address>
                </address>
            </Node>
        </Story>
        <Build>
            <Action category="build_value_1">Build was successful</Action>
        </Build>
        <OtherData type="string" meaning="favoriteTVShow">Purple</OtherData>
        <OtherData type="string" meaning="favoriteColor">Seinfeld</OtherData>
    </Alarm>
</ROOT-MAIN>
```

I am trying to build an array of dictionaries that have a similar structure to the second **< Alarm >** object. When parsing this XML file, I do the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data/'+filename)
root = tree.getroot()


namespace= '{http://fakeurl.com/page}'

for alarm in tree.findall(namespace+'Alarm'):
    for elem in alarm.iter():
        try:
            creation_time = elem.find(namespace+'CreateTime')
            for story in elem.findall(namespace+'Story'):
                for node in story.findall(namespace+'Node'):
                    for Address in node.findall(namespace+'Address'):
                        address = Address.find(namespace+'address').text

            for build in elem.findall(namespace+'Build'):
                category= build.find(namespace+'Action').attrib
                action = build.find(namespace+'Action').text
            
            for otherdata in elem.findall(namespace+'OtherData'):
                #not sure how to get the 'meaning' attribute value as well as the text value for these <OtherData> tags  
        except:
            pass
```

Right I'm just trying to get values for:

1. < address >
2. < Action > (attribute value and text value)
3. < OtherData > (attribute value and text value)

I'm sort of able to do this with for loops within for-loops but I was hoping for a cleaner, xpath solution which I haven't figured out how to do with a namespace.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here (collecting a subset of the elements you mentioned -- add more code to collect rest of elements)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

xmlstring = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://fakeurl.com/page">
    <Alarm> 
        <Node>
            <location>Texas></location>
            <name>John</name>
        </Node>
    </Alarm>

    <Alarm> 
        <CreateTime>01/01/2011</CreateTime>

        <Story>
            <Node>
                <Name>Ethan</Name>
                <Address category="residential">
                    <address>1421 Morning SE</address>
                </Address>
            </Node>
        </Story>

        <Build>
            <Action category="build_value_1">Build was successful</Action>
        </Build>
        <OtherData type="string" meaning="favoriteTVShow">Purple</OtherData>
        <OtherData type="string" meaning="favoriteColor">Seinfeld</OtherData>
    </Alarm>
</root>'''

xmlstring = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', xmlstring, count=1)

root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)
alarms = root.findall('Alarm')
alarms_list = []
for alarm in alarms:
    create_time = alarm.find('CreateTime')
    if create_time is not None:
        entry = {'create_time': create_time.text}
        alarms_list.append(entry)
        actions = alarm.findall('Build/Action')
        if actions:
            entry['builds'] = []
        for action in actions:
            entry['builds'].append({'category': action.attrib['category'], 'status': action.text})

print(alarms_list)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @balderman. Good idea with stripping out the namespace